# How to package VS Code Extension behind proxy

Tags: visual-studio-code, proxy, vscode-extensions

I have created a VS Code extension that I want to distribute within my organization. My system runs behind a corporate proxy threfore when I try to create a publisher using the command `vsce create-publisher (publisher name)` I get following error:

```
 ERROR  tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=407
```

It does not accept --proxy-server option that VS Code supports while installing extensions.

Answer (score 1):

proxies are not supported by VSCE for now. It can published outside corporate networks only. This issue is open for last three years on github.

Please find this issue link.
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-vsce/issues/157